# Why is Kotlins type inference failing when Javas isn't?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, type-inference

Given the following code (which uses a dummy return but shows the issue):

```
import com.github.roookeee.datus.api.Datus
import com.github.roookeee.datus.api.Mapper
import com.github.roookeee.datus.immutable.ConstructorParameter

data class EntryDto(val id: Long?, val title: String, val content: String)
data class EntryEntity(val id: Long? = null, val title: String, val content: String) {
    fun toDto(): EntryDto {
        val mapper: Mapper<EntryEntity, EntryDto> = Datus.forTypes(this.javaClass, EntryDto::class.java)
                .immutable(::EntryDto)
                .from(EntryEntity::id).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                .from(EntryEntity::title).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                .from(EntryEntity::content).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                .build()
        return EntryDto(null, "", "")
    }
}
```

Kotlin is not able to infer the correct generic types whereas Java >= 8 does (given two Java classes that are identical to the data classes here - two immutable object classes). I tried with the defaults for Kotlin 1.3.0 and `-XXLanguage:+NewInference` but the later couldn't even infer the right overload to pick for `.immutable`.

Here is the datus dependency information to make the above code compile (I can't reduce this problem without the library, it's too complex in its generic usage):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.roookeee</groupId>
    <artifactId>datus</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something? I would love to make my library more compatible with kotlin but am at a loss how to go from here or what the exact name of the inference error is.

You can find datus sources [here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus).

This is the corresponding java code:

```
import com.github.roookeee.datus.api.Datus;
import com.github.roookeee.datus.api.Mapper;
import com.github.roookeee.datus.immutable.ConstructorParameter;

class Java8Code {
    static class EntryDto {
        private final Long id;
        private final String title;
        private final String content;

        EntryDto(Long id, String title, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
    }

    static class EntryEntity {
        private final Long id;
        private final String title;
        private final String content;

        EntryEntity(Long id, String title, String content) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public EntryDto toDto() {
            Mapper<EntryEntity, EntryDto> mapper = Datus.forTypes(EntryEntity.class, EntryDto.class)
                    .immutable(EntryDto::new)
                    .from(EntryEntity::getId).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                    .from(EntryEntity::getTitle).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                    .from(EntryEntity::getContent).to(ConstructorParameter::bind)
                    .build();
            return mapper.convert(this);
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT 2: An image of the error message + some notes below
[image]

`3 type arguments expected for interface ConstructorParameter<In : Any!, GetterReturnType : Any!, Result : Any!>` - Kotlin seems to expect generic type parameters for the interfaces method reference but that simply isn't possible in Kotlin nor needed in Java.

Comment: Can you provide the Java 8 code sample which behaves as you expect?

Comment: I will say I believe this has something to do with Kotlin's [`to()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html) extension function.

Comment: I have done what you asked for :) Don't I need to import `to()` to be an issue here? My IDE complains about not enough type information to infer so I don't think its about your linked extension function

Comment: Try replacing `to` calls with a lambda instead of method reference: (`to { param, getter -> param.bind(getter) }`, I guess? Having a JavaDoc to see types would help.) I have previously seen it help with type parameter inference.

Comment: yeah that works but its really cumbersome to do :( I thought I could add some type hints for kotlin (e.g. an annotation). You know anything about that? The main problem persists: Kotlins type inference is failing here

Comment: Maybe [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-builder-inference/index.html) can help? Can't find any resources for it though... would love to at least have a ticket on the kotlin issue tracker, but all the generic issues are explained in a way that I can't map to my problem easily

Comment: It would be great if you can provide the error messages.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung done :)

Answer (score 1):

The `to` extension function is not the problem. It just pops up because the compiler does not see the correct parameter for the member method.

What Kotlin doesn't like, is the generic type without the type parameter attached. `ConstructorParameter` is not a type until you specify the type parameters. So it complains when it sees `ConstructorParameter::bind`, the left hand side of `::` should be a type.

If you write `.to { x, y -> x.bind(y) }`, Kotlin can infer the type just fine.
But you can't expect your users to write this "same" lambda so many times.

Extension functions to the rescue!

```
fun <In, CurrentType, Next> ConstructorParameterBinding<In, CurrentType, out ConstructorParameter<In, CurrentType, Next>>.bind(): Next =
    this.to { x, y -> x.bind(y) }

val mapper: Mapper<EntryEntity, EntryDto> = Datus.forTypes(this.javaClass, EntryDto::class.java)
    .immutable(::EntryDto)
    .from(EntryEntity::id).bind()
    .from(EntryEntity::title).bind()
    .from(EntryEntity::content).bind()
    .build()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, tried extensions functions too so I knew this one already. I have two (subjective, library related) issues with this approach: 1) I need to release a second artifact for kotlin support 2) the general flow of `from().map().to()` is broken which I worked so hard to unify for the mutable and immutable API of datus. Any ideas on how to keep the mentioned flow? I would love the Java and Kotlin flow to be the same if possible. Nice to have this answer here for documentations sake though :)

Comment: It still baffles me that a more type inference focused language like Kotlin doesn't handle this as well as Java :o